How to get projected stats for a player using Yahoo fantasy API
I'm trying to get the projected stats for the upcoming season with:
GET https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/player/454.p.6355/stats;type=season?format=json
but I'm getting "-" as value for every stat.
It's like passing

type=season

it's giving me the stats for the next season that didn't start yet.
However, in the Yahoo page they are showing the project stats, I'm assuming there should be a way.
Checking the official doc(https://developer.yahoo.com/fantasysports/guide/) and can't find a way.
